# Smart auto-completition for staged git file names, used with difftool

Tags: git, bash, console, terminal

I'd like to have a smart  auto-completition of currently staged file names when using git diff.

Example:

```
modified:   DIR1/LongCamelCaseFileName.h
modified:   DIR1/AnotherLongCamelCaseFileName.m
modified:   DIR1/AndThereAreALotOfThemInDir1.m
modified:   DIR2/file4.m
```

and here, using bash tab-auto-complete functionality I'd like to use it with

```
git diff
```

where by smart I mean that after typing git diff I'd need to type only a short part of the staged file name that I want to diff, and without a dirname, so for example

```
git diff And<TAB>
```

would result in

```
git diff DIR1/AndThereAreALotOfThemInDir1.m
```

Actually, without a dir-ommiting-part it would be still useful (auto-completing using only staged files pool).

Answer (score 4):

This would be a nice feature, but there are already few alternatives, e.g.:

Interactive mode:

```
git add -i
```

Wildcards:

```
git add *And*
```